# Como capturar imagem da camera do celular e mandar para o servidor via rest utilizando o volley?

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, web-service, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao *MOBILE* que se comunica com minha aplicação web, o aplicativo desenvolvido no *Android Studio* e o web no *PlayFramework*. Criei um formulário no *APK* que já faz o consumo do serviço via rest utilizando vólei, tudo já funcionando, porem falta somente enviar a imagem juntamente com os demais campos do formulário. Como estou aprendendo agora a criar e consumir serviços, estou com dificuldade para enviar a imagem capturada pelo celular no formulário. Alguém pode me ajudar.

**Minha classe do forms no AS:**

```
public class DenunciaActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, LocationListener {

double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;
public static final String TAG = "LOG";
//public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.112.3.154:9000/Services/denuncia";
public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.0.103:9000/Services/denuncia";
EditText femail, frua, fbairro, fcompl, fcidade, festado, fpais, fobs;
public String name;
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "nome";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "rua";
public static final String KEY_DISTRICT = "bairro";
public static final String KEY_COMPLEMENT = "complemento";
public static final String KEY_CITY = "cidade";
public static final String KEY_STATE = "estado";
public static final String KEY_NOTE = "observacao";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "data";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_LAT = "latitude";
public static final String KEY_LONG = "longitude";
public static final String KEY_COUNTRIE = "pais";
public static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date data = new Date();
String dataFormatada = formataData.format(data);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_denuncia );
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    readMyCurrentCoordinates();
    Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    name = inBundle.get("name").toString();
    frua = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rua);
    fbairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bairro);
    fcompl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.complemento);
    fcidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cidade);
    festado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.estado);
    fpais = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pais);
    fobs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.observacao);
    femail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        EditText nome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome);
        nome.setText(name, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    Button enviar = (Button) findViewById( R.id.enviar );


    enviar.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(valid() == true){
                registerForms();
            }
        }
    } );


}
public void tirarFoto(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(data != null){
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto anexada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
public void registerForms() {

    final String address = frua.getText().toString().trim();
    final String district = fbairro.getText().toString().trim();
    final String city = fcidade.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = femail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String complement = fcompl.getText().toString().trim();
    final String state = festado.getText().toString().trim();
    final String note = fobs.getText().toString().trim();
    final String countries = fpais.getText().toString().trim();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.contains("Erro")) {
                Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DenunciaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    Log.i( TAG, "Lat: " + error );
                }
            } ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put( KEY_USERNAME, name );
            map.put( KEY_DATE, dataFormatada );
            map.put( KEY_STATE, state );
            map.put( KEY_CITY, city );
            map.put( KEY_DISTRICT, district );
            map.put( KEY_ADDRESS, address );
            map.put( KEY_EMAIL, email );
            map.put( KEY_COMPLEMENT, complement );
            map.put( KEY_COUNTRIE, countries );
            map.put( KEY_LAT, String.valueOf( latitude ) );
            map.put( KEY_LONG, String.valueOf( longitude ) );
            map.put( KEY_NOTE, note );
            map.put( KEY_STATUS, "ATIVO" );
            Log.i( TAG, "Lat: " + longitude +" "+latitude);
            return map;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this );
    requestQueue.add( stringRequest );
}

}
```

**Do outro lado, o meu serviço:**

```
public class Services extends Controller {
public static void denuncia(@Valid String nome, String data, String rua, String bairro, String complemento, String cidade, String estado, String pais, String observacao, String email, String latitude, String longitude, Status status) {
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        String mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar";
        JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
        j.addProperty("Erro", 404);
        j.addProperty("msg", mensagem);
        renderJSON(j);
    } else {
        String msgsucess = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
        Denuncia denuncia = new Denuncia();
        denuncia.nome = nome;
        denuncia.data = data;
        denuncia.rua = rua;
        denuncia.bairro = bairro;
        denuncia.complemento = complemento;
        denuncia.cidade = cidade;
        denuncia.estado = estado;
        denuncia.pais = pais;
        denuncia.observacao = observacao;
        denuncia.email = email;
        denuncia.latitude = latitude;
        denuncia.longitude = longitude;
        denuncia.status = status;
        denuncia.save();
        JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
        j.addProperty("Success", 200);
        j.addProperty("msg", msgsucess);
        renderJSON(j);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Voce quer enviar essa imagem via form-data? ou Base64?

Comment: enviar via base64 @LMaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue código que eu uso em um dos aplicativos meus legados, mas resolve seu problema. Você vai colocar ele junto no onActivityResult:

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
String foto = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Somente tome cuidado com o tamanho do request, muitos servidores web limitam o tamanho do mesmo.

Comment: CDS Informatica como fica no meu model? Coloquei public String foto; e deu erro Value too long for column "FOTO VARCHAR(255)": "STRINGDECODE('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD....

Comment: Se estiver fazendo persistência de dados (que é o que parece, é uma coluna de banco, me corrija se estiver errado), você tem que aumentar o tamanho da coluna, com um tipo que seja de texto, sem tamanho. Ou criar um tipo blob no banco de dados e converter de base64 para byte[] e gravar nessa coluna.

Comment: Ou criar um tipo blob no banco de dados e converter de base64 para byte[] e gravar nessa coluna. Tentar fazer isso

Comment: CDS Informatica pode me ajudar aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267116/erro-ao-salvar-imagem-jpeg-no-banco-como-string-base64/267119?noredirect=1#comment547624_267119 ainda estou enganchado