# Erro ao salvar imagem JPEG no banco como string (base64)

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, web-service, imagem

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicativo que tem um formulário onde o usuário pode anexar uma foto junto ao form. Porem estou com dificuldade em implementar isto. No meu APK eu ja capturo a imagem, converto em base 64 e envio via Rest para meu serviço.

```
public void tirarFoto(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(data != null){
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto anexada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            foto = Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        }
    }
}
public void registerForms() {

    final String address = frua.getText().toString().trim();
    final String district = fbairro.getText().toString().trim();
    final String city = fcidade.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = femail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String complement = fcompl.getText().toString().trim();
    final String state = festado.getText().toString().trim();
    final String note = fobs.getText().toString().trim();
    final String countries = fpais.getText().toString().trim();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DenunciaActivity.this, "Aguarde um momento", "Enviando...", true, false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if (response.contains("Erro")) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, "Erro ao enviar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(DenunciaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, "Enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText( DenunciaActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    Log.i( TAG, "Lat: " + error );
                }
            } ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put( KEY_USERNAME, name );
            map.put( KEY_DATE, dataFormatada );
            map.put( KEY_STATE, state );
            map.put( KEY_CITY, city );
            map.put( KEY_DISTRICT, district );
            map.put( KEY_ADDRESS, address );
            map.put( KEY_EMAIL, email );
            map.put( KEY_COMPLEMENT, complement );
            map.put( KEY_COUNTRIE, countries );
            map.put( KEY_LAT, String.valueOf( latitude ) );
            map.put( KEY_LONG, String.valueOf( longitude ) );
            map.put( KEY_NOTE, note );
            map.put( KEY_STATUS, "ATIVO" );
            map.put( KEY_IMAGE, foto );
            Log.i( TAG, "Lat: " + longitude +" "+latitude);
            return map;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this );
    requestQueue.add( stringRequest );
}
```

No meu serviço esta assim:

```
public class Services extends Controller {
public static void denuncia(@Valid String nome, String data, String rua, String bairro, String complemento, String cidade, String estado, String pais, String observacao, String email, String latitude, String longitude, Status status, String foto) {
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        String mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar";
        JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
        j.addProperty("Erro", 404);
        j.addProperty("msg", mensagem);
        renderJSON(j);
    } else {
        String msgsucess = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
        Denuncia denuncia = new Denuncia();
        denuncia.nome = nome;
        denuncia.data = data;
        denuncia.rua = rua;
        denuncia.bairro = bairro;
        denuncia.complemento = complemento;
        denuncia.cidade = cidade;
        denuncia.estado = estado;
        denuncia.pais = pais;
        denuncia.observacao = observacao;
        denuncia.email = email;
        denuncia.latitude = latitude;
        denuncia.longitude = longitude;
        denuncia.status = status;
        denuncia.foto = foto;
        denuncia.save();
        JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
        j.addProperty("Success", 200);
        j.addProperty("msg", msgsucess);
        renderJSON(j);
    }
}
```

E o meu Model esta:

```
@Entity
public class Denuncia extends Model{

@Required
public String nome;
@Required
public String rua;
@Required
public String bairro;
@Required
public String complemento;
@Required
public String data;
@Required
public String cidade;
@Required
public String estado;
@Required
public String pais;
@Required
public String observacao;
@Required
@Email
public String email;
public String foto;
public String latitude; 
public String longitude;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status statusMsg;
public Denuncia() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
    statusMsg = Status.NAO_LIDA;
}
```

O erro que estou passando é referente ao tamanho da string que estou recebendo no meu banco, é maior do que o suportado, conforme a saida:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column "FOTO VARCHAR(255)": "STRINGDECODE('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB\nAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB... (62229)"; SQL statement:
insert into Denuncia (id, bairro, cidade, complemento, data, email, estado, foto, latitude, longitude, nome, observacao, pais, rua, status, statusMsg) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [22001-193]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:335)
at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:784)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
... 30 more
```

Alguem me ajudar a achar uma saída para o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você definiu a coluna de imagens como `VARCHAR(255)`.

Em geral o tipo `varchar` armazena de um a dois bytes por caractere (supondo UTF-8).

Isso significa que qualquer imagem que você tentar guardar com mais de 123 bytes vai dar esse erro. Sim, eu disse bytes.

Salvei a sua foto de avatar aqui na minha máquina pra ver o tamanho. Ela ocupa 8192 bytes em disco.

Utilize um tamanho de coluna maior. E se for salvar arquivos, facilite sua vida - tente um formato binário (blob ou algo do tipo).

Comment: Como poderia fazer isso usando esse blob? pq essa tabela terá varias imagens, mas como nunca fiz isso (upload de imagem para banco) nao sei como implementar e qual a melhor maneira

Comment: @CarlosDiego sinto muito, eu sou um zero à esquerda em Java :( não conheço a API.

Comment: A melhor maneira é salvar as imagens no disco e gravar o caminho no banco de dados. Salvar arquivos enormes no banco de dados não é recomendado.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr discordo com todas as minhas forças. Os tipos binários foram criados para isso. Se você não armazenar os arquivos na base, você correrá o sério risco de ter inconsistências com o tempo. E seus backups da base não incluirão os arquivos, logo qualquer restauração em outra máquina será inválida sem um outro backup mais complexo e externo ao banco.

Comment: @Renan apesar dos tipos binários serem criados para isso, o uso de memória será bem maior. Visto que o projeto dele deverá utilizar bastante buscas no DB, eu particularmente (não sou DBA), optaria por outra forma. Claro que ele pode utilizar o banco de dados como uma forma mais segura e confiável (é inegável esse pró do banco de dados), mas ele terá que optar por utilizar um cache para evitar o consumo desenfreado de RAM e provavelmente será no disco rígido. E não pode esquecer: *"Com grandes banco de dados, vem grandes responsabilidades."*

Comment: Deixo aqui alguns links do porquê considero uma solução melhor (principalmente se tiver trabalhando sozinho e não tiver um grande conhecimento em DBA). 1. https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/; 2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-blob.html; 3. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server e 4. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787